# $\ln(n)$ - Average Length of Prime Gaps

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

The natural logarithm of $n$ is a good approximation of the prime gap near $n$. On my calculator I enter this as $\ln(n)$.

I have read from these pages:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Large_prime_gap_conjecture

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture

https://primes.utm.edu/notes/gaps.html

I want to make sure that I am using my calculator correctly and that $\ln(n)$ is the **average** prime gap near $n$ as proven by the prime number theorem.

The question I have is concerning the **average** length of the prime gap near $n$ and the proof that such an **average** exists for all $n$.

Comment: I'd say "near $n$." There are a lot of numbers above $n$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By PNT we have $p_{k}\sim k\log\left(k\right)$ so $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\leq n-1}\left(p_{k+1}-p_{k}\right)\sim\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\leq n-1}\left(\left(k+1\right)\log\left(k+1\right)-k\log\left(k\right)\right)$$ $$\sim\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\leq n-1}\log\left(k+1\right)\left(k+1-k\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\leq n}\log\left(k\right)\sim\log\left(n\right)
 $$ since $$\log\left(k+1\right)-\log\left(k\right)=o\left(1\right)
 $$ and $$\sum_{k\leq n}\log\left(k\right)=n\log\left(n\right)-n+O\left(\log(n)\right).$$